# when *only* adding tags, I see the "... must be at least 6..." message. why?

Tags: discussion, bug

when I edit some questions [like this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/11293/edit), *only* adding  tags, I see the "... must be at least 6..." message. why?

---

**Update.** I want to add the "UK" for tags, [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11505/why-do-other-countries-in-the-eu-care-so-strongly-that-the-uk-accepts-free-movem), but see the comment "... must be at least 6..." .

Comment: There is an edit tags link have you tried that?

Comment: @Chad - there's a rep threshold for that link IIRC

Comment: I just added it, so it seems like you can only add tags (or combinations of tags) that are at least six letters until your reputation passes the 2k mark.